# Wait on RxJs.Subscription before resuming

Tags: rxjs

How can I wait for a subscription to finish before resuming my method?

Let there be a `SettingService` which fetches settings from the server once and then caches them. It provides a `get(key): Setting` method for its consumers and ensures that only a single instance of a setting with the same key exists. This has two implications:

- It must ensure the settings are downloaded / cached only once
- It has to handle the case where a consumer might ask the service too early (before the download is finished).

What I have so far:

```
export class SettingService {
    private settings: Setting[] = [];
    private settingSubscription: Subscription;
    private settingLoaded: Boolean = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.initSettings();
    }

    private initSettings() {
        this.settingSubscription = this.http.get<Setting[]>('api/Setting').subscribe(s => {
            this.settings = s;
            this.settingLoaded = true;
        });
    }

    get(key: string): Setting {
        if (!this.settingLoaded) {
            //TODO: wait for settingSubscription to finish
        }

        return this.resolveSetting(key);
    }

    private resolveSetting(key: String) {
        //uses this.settings to retreive the setting
    }
}
```

This question is very similar to [Wait on RxJs.Subscriptions to finish before resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126153/wait-on-rxjs-subscriptions-to-finish-before-resuming), except that I must ensure that the async method is executed just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem will be solved if you follow "Reactive mantra":

[image: Reactive mantra]

see [The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) to understand what does that mean.

With this idea in mind `Settings` service can be done as following:

```js
const { timer } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { map, mapTo, shareReplay } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

// emulate making ajax request
function loadSettings() {
  console.log('request to load settings ...');

  return timer(2000).pipe(
    mapTo({
      a: 'a-value',
      b: 'b-value'
    })
  );
}

// Settings service
const settings$ = loadSettings().pipe(
  shareReplay(1) // cache result
);
const get = key => settings$.pipe(
  map(s => s[key] || 'default')
);

// usage example
get('a').subscribe(v => console.log("result for a: ", v));
setTimeout(
  () => get('unknown').subscribe(v => console.log("result for unknown:", v)), 
  5000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.3.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

As a recap:

- keep everything* as Observable
- 1 subscription for the entire app is enough

Comment: Coming from a c# background, the async mantra was `everything is an object`, of yourse I got confused. Your example helped to solve my problem and the "real" introduction was/is very helpful, thanks for the link!